# NPM fails any command silently. How to change npm config manually?

Tags: npm

I was trying to set a certificate for npm (npm config set cafile) when it suddenly gave up entirely and any command would just result in two empty lines and then nothing:

[image]

Since nothing works I can't try to unset my certificate to see if that helps.

Can I change the npm settings somewhere manually? Alternatively, how can I reset all npm settings on my system?

I've tried to uninstall and re-install node+npm but it still behaves the same.

Answer (score -1):

I found the faulty setting in C:\Users{User}.npmrc, and after I fixed that npm came back to life.